# What do @ and lambda mean in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Just trying to "port" some Python code to Java, I came then across the following python code:

```
 @fake(lambda s, t, n: [(s.field(i+1), s) for i in range(n)])
 def split(secret, threshold, num_players):
     shares = []
     for i in range(1, num_players+1):
         # do some shares calculation
     return shares
```

There are quite some interesting constructs in this one that I never noticed before. Could anyone tell me what is the deal with this @fake thingy?

```
def fake(replacement):
    """Replace a function with a fake version."""
    def decorator(func):
        fakes = os.environ.get('FUNC_FAKE', '')
        if fakes == '*' or func.__name__ in fakes.split():
            return replacement
        else:
            return func
    return decorator
```

Further, does this lambda stand for a function name or what is the deal with that?

Comment: It's using a decorator. Please post the implementation of the `fake` function, also include what is below that line.

Comment: See [Understanding Python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) and the tutorial note on [lambda forms](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms).

Comment: I assume the second line in `fake` ends with three quotes? If not, what you pasted is incomplete.

Comment: You have two separate questions here. I think you will find that each has been asked many times before (though "decorator" is not an obvious search term if you don't know what the feature is called).

Comment: One part that was never highlighted in this answer or the supposingly duplicate one, is how a Java custom annotation can be used as a direct correlation for Python Decorators. I vote, to reopen

Comment: @Abhijit It’s not possible. Python decorators are exactly that: decorators. They replace the decorated function by something else that is compatible to it. On the other hand, annotations are just some kind of meta-information you can attach to things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `@fake` is a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators).

What `@fake` appears to do is to conditionally replace the function that follows, i.e. `split`, with the lambda function (note how the two take the same parameters).

The decision is based on the `FUNC_FAKE` environment variable. If the latter equals `*` or contains `split` as one of its tokens, the replacement is made. Otherwise, it isn't.

The fact that the replacement is a [lambda function](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) is not important. It could have just as easily been made into a normal function:

```
def split_replacement(s, t, n):
   return [(s.field(i+1), s) for i in range(n)])

@fake(split_replacement)
def split(s, t, n):
   ...
```

This whole construct is rather baffling. I struggle to come up with a reason for doing things this way, other than to try and confuse other programmers (or to play with decorators).

Comment: You could even do `@fake` <NL> `def fake_split_replacement(...):` ... and then use this "simply-decorated" function as a decorator itself: `@fake_split_replacement` <NL> `def split(...):`, if you need it at several places.

Comment: BTW, I disagree. This construct seems quite helpful to me, and I don't see a problem here...

Answer (score 4):

The first question is answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators).

For your second question:

```
x = lambda a, b, *args, **kwargs: <expression>
```

is just a shorthand for

```
def x(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    return <expression>
```

See also [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Comment: Could you PLEASE refrain from downvoting while I am still writing?!

Comment: “Answer on lambda (I am writing)” – Why don’t you just click save once (and only once) you have actually written something useful?

Comment: @poke I wanted to remain able to provide something useful before the question was closed... there were already 4 close votes.